# PyQGIS custom application: no GUI appearing

Tags: pyqgis, gui, standalone

I'm following the following instructions on getting Python to work with QGIS, outside the QGIS GUI itself: [Using PyQGIS in custom applications](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-custom-applications).

But for some reason the GUI is not appearing, yet the layer seems to be loading fine and it also returns the correct feature count. What am I doing wrong?

```py
from qgis.core import *

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

qgs.initQgis()

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("test.gpkg")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    raise Exception("Layer failed to load!")


project = QgsProject.instance()
project.addMapLayer(vlayer)

print(vlayer.featureCount());

# Write your code here to load some layers, use processing
# algorithms, etc.

qgs.exitQgis()
```

Comment: You create a Qt / PyQGIS main loop and run some code in it. Have you instantiate widgets and show them ? `my_widget = QgsColorDialog(); my_widget.show()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any GUI doesn't appear when using PyQGIS standalone application. You have to construct it.

Here is an example:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *

### GUI Construction ###
class MapViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, None)

        self._canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self._root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

        self.bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(self._root, self._canvas)
        self.model = QgsLayerTreeModel(self._root)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.ShowLegend)
        self.layer_treeview = QgsLayerTreeView()
        self.layer_treeview.setModel(self.model)

        self.layer_tree_dock = QDockWidget("Layers")
        self.layer_tree_dock.setObjectName("layers")
        self.layer_tree_dock.setFeatures(QDockWidget.NoDockWidgetFeatures)
        self.layer_tree_dock.setWidget(self.layer_treeview)

        self.splitter = QSplitter()
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.layer_tree_dock)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self._canvas)
        self.splitter.setCollapsible(0, False)
        self.splitter.setStretchFactor(1, 1)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.contents = QWidget()
        self.contents.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.contents)

        self.load_layers()

    def load_layers(self):
        # Adding a sample layer
        layer = QgsVectorLayer("test.gpkg", 'Layer1', 'ogr') # CHANGE PATH
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        self._canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        self._canvas.setLayers([layer])
########################
        
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

### Call the GUI built by you ###
main_window = MapViewer()
main_window.show()

qgs.exec_()
qgs.exitQgis()
```

[image]

Comment: Got it; it wasn't entirely clear from the instructions here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications that I needed to construct the GUI myself. Now it is :) Thanks!

Comment: What is this flag? `self.model.setFlag(0x25043)`

Comment: I'll try to decipher the bitmask tomorrow, should be fairly easy. Thanks for this great example BTW! OK if I try to add it to the official docs?

Comment: @bugmenot123 no problem.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I found what `0x25043` is. It is the sum of flags set (20000+4000+1000+20+10+8+4+1=25043) . [Check this](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgslayertreemodel_8h_source.html#l00097).